# Programming a DBSCAN in Mathematica

Tags: options, cluster-analysis

`FindClusters` has a built-in `Method` called `"DBSCAN"`. You can find it on this page:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PartitioningDataIntoClusters.html.

There you can also find two important additional options for the `"DBSCAN"` which are `"NeighborhoodRadius"` and `"NeighborsNumber"`. In a `"DBSCAN"` the algorithm establishes Core points: If they contain the needed amount of points in their neighborhood, given by `"NeighborsNumber"` (which should be treated as minimum points needed), and the neighborhood has the size of `"NeighborhoodRadius"` (which therefore has to be used as a maximum). But as you can read on the page I linked, they are used as averages in the *Mathematica*'s implementation of the method. Doing it like this will give very bad results when using this function.

I'm new to programming in *Mathematica* so any help on programming a DBSCAN with the values set to maximum and minimum instead of average would be great even if it's only a small part of the program.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well i dont know of a way to fix it without programming a completly knew DBSCAN so i did that in java because i have programmed alot in java and i have one that that works but i cant get anything to work in mathematica

Comment: If this is a holdup for you, consider using [JLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/Overview.html) to load your Java function until you have solved it.

Comment: Just an update if anyone cares about a fixed DBSCAN im still working on it and its nearly done

Answer (score 1):

You will find examples in [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalOperationsOnData.html#2948) where they indicate you can set specific values for each of those options like this:

```
clusters=FindClusters[datapairs,Method->{"DBSCAN",
   "NeighborhoodRadius"->0.2,"NeighborsNumber"->40}];
ListPlot[clusters]
```